# Calculating points on line with endpoints

Tags: python, line, pygame

Using Python 2.7.3 and Pygame 1.9.1.

I have a line and I only know the co-ordinates of endpoints A and B.
I want to calculate what are the co-ordinates AB, given a value on x or y axis.
**For Example**
[image: Image Example]

**Here I know**
`(x,y)` of `A` **,** `B`&`C`
**Also,**
`C` is on X-axis or Y axis.
**My Question**
How do I calculate the position of the Co-ordinates(x,y) of point `D`

Comment: Do you know how to set up the equation of a straight line?

Comment: @MatteoItalia No.. But just searched that on Google. So now, Yes.

Comment: Well you could have looked it up at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the straight line is:

```
y = mx + q
```

What you want is either `y(x)` or `x(y)`, and you have the two endpoints `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. Replace them in the straight-line equation and set up a linear system:

```
y1 = m·x1 + q
y2 = m·x2 + q
```

Subtraction yields:

```
y2-y1 = m(x2-x1) => m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

and q is obviously:

```
q = y2-m·x2
```

so, now you have your `y = f(x)` representing the straight line connecting your two points.

Obviously, a vertical line cannot be represented in this form (`m->+inf`), and, if you are trying to trace a line on pixels evaluating this function for every x, you'll get vertical "holes".
In both these cases, you should use the `x = f(y)` form (that you can obtain following these same steps, but starting from the equation `x = py + r`).

That being said, you can get the `y` of `D` knowing its `x` by just putting such `x` in the equation of the straight line (`y = f(x)`) determined above; the same holds (with the inverse relation, `x = f(y)`) if you know the `y` and want to determine the `x`.